# a[download] attribute fall back for IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Is there any fallback available for `download` attribute of Anchor tag to deal with IE ?

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/download) says it's not supported in any version if Internet Explorer.

Solution without JavaScript is preferable.

Comment: Letting people use File > Save As works.

Comment: `old is gold` but I would like to know if there is any other way.

Comment: you can use server side technology (C#) to accomplish this...

Answer (score 4):

As of now, the `download` attribute is only supported in [Chrome and Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility). You could detect whether the attribute is supported using JavaScript.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');

if(typeof a.download != "undefined")
{
   // download attribute is supported
}
else
{
  // download attribute is not supported
}
```

If you are dealing with text files then you could take a look at [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), which is a javascript + Flash library that enables the creation and download of text files without server interaction. Check out this [Demo](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) that uses Downloadify.

Comment: Interesting library. However there are lots of other ways using JS. just wanna know if there is any hack for IE. I hope MS guys will think about it for their next versions.